# Git: Pushing to and Pulling from my Remote Server Takes A Long Time

Tags: git, apache, http, debian

I have Apache2 running on Debian hosting a git repository. I have configured the git-http-backend plugin and everything is working.

The only problem is: it takes forever to push and pull. Sometimes up to 3 minutes.

This would be expected of a large repository, but all I have in my repo is a README file that is ~1K in size.

I have configured my DNS to point to the IP address of my router, and pinging my domain returns the correct IP instantly, so there's no hang-up there.

When I push to and pull from my server's local network IP address, it finishes before I fully release the enter key.

My best guess is that there's something holding up the connection in my router. It's an NVG589 from Motorola for anyone that's interested. Also, to allow access to the server, I've opened ports 80 (HTTP) 22 (SSH) and 9418 (git) on both TCP and UDP.

Any ideas as to why this is happening would be greatly appreciated.

Best regards,

George

Comment: It could be because of several reasons. Since, you say you are able to pull and push properly, though taking a longer time, it means you have a functional setup. Two common reasons that I have faced commonly for such a problem are: 1. DNS lookup 2. [git gc](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-gc.html).

Comment: DNS lookup can't be it because when I push to and pull from the IP address directly, it takes the same amount of time. `git gc` wouldn't do anything because my repository is brand new and only has one file.

Comment: Then, I would try to see a verbose log of the communication between the git server and the client.

Comment: `--verbose` yields nothing. There's just a huge pause in the middle of `Pushing to http://user@myserver` and `To http://user@myserver`.

Comment: You can try `GIT_TRACE=2 git fetch -a`, and get a little more information.  `GIT_TRACE=2 GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 GIT_TRACE_PACKET=1 git fetch -a` will dump much more information about what is happening at the network level.

Comment: I meant the ssh verbose output rather, `ssh -vT git@...`.

Comment: I'm using HTTP. SSH is minutely faster. However, I need to use HTTP. Running it with `GIT_TRACE=2` yields `* - Conn 0 (0x7fef59811800) send_pipe: 0, recv_pipe: 0
* - Conn 1 (0x7fef5a800000) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
!!!REALLY LONG PAUSE!!! * Connected to *the ip* (*the ip*) port 80 (#1)`

Comment: @GeorgeMorgan  I am facing similar kind of issue. There is long pause in pull and push. Did you find any solution or reason for this.

Comment: It's been a while since I worked on this project, but if I recall correctly, it was a problem with my router. I was using my router's public IP address to host my repository and my router had some sort of setting that I changed to fix the problem. I don't remember what that setting was! Hope this helps.